# How can we reduce if else condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

> I am working on node js and mysql here i am using profile incomplete or complete logic so i have to check all the fields or empty or not so i have 28 fields i have used 28 if else can we make shorter code.

> Here my code
> so how we can reduce my code if we can reduce our code please share your solution.

> Here no error this code is correct But I need to make shorter code it will be good.

```
let points = 0;
        let point1 = 0;
        let point2 = 0;
        let point3 = 0;
        let point4 = 0;
        let point5 = 0;
        let point6 = 0;
        let point7 = 0;
        let point8 = 0;
        let point9 = 0;
        let point10 = 0;
        let point11 = 0;
        let point12 = 0;
        let point13 = 0;
        let point14 = 0;
        let point15 = 0;
        let point16 = 0;
        let point17 = 0;
        let point18 = 0;
        let point19 = 0;
        let point20 = 0;
        let point21 = 0;
        let point22 = 0;
        let point23 = 0;
        let point24 = 0;
        let point25 = 0;
        let point26 = 0;

        if (profileRes[0].username == null || profileRes[0].username == "") {
            point1 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].username != null || profileRes[0].username != "") {
            point1 = points += 0;
        }
        if (profileRes[0].phone == null || profileRes[0].phone == "") {
            point2 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].phone != null || profileRes[0].phone != "") {
            point2 = points += 0;
        }
        if (profileRes[0].email == null || profileRes[0].email == "") {
            point3 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].email != null || profileRes[0].email != "") {
            point3 = points += 0;
        }
        if (profileRes[0].company_name == null || profileRes[0].company_name == "") {
            point4 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].company_name != null || profileRes[0].company_name != "") {
            point4 = points += 0;
        }
        if (profileRes[0].profile_description == null || profileRes[0].profile_description == "") {
            point5 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].profile_description != null || profileRes[0].profile_description != "") {
            point5 = points += 0;
        }
        if (profileRes[0].short_description == null || profileRes[0].short_description == "") {
            point6 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].short_description != null || profileRes[0].short_description != "") {
            point6 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].company_url == null || profileRes[0].company_url == "") {
            point7 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].company_url != null || profileRes[0].company_url != "") {
            point7 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].company_linkedin == null || profileRes[0].company_linkedin == "") {
            point8 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].company_linkedin != null || profileRes[0].company_linkedin != "") {
            point8 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].company_instagram == null || profileRes[0].company_instagram == "") {
            point9 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].company_instagram != null || profileRes[0].company_instagram != "") {
            point9 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].company_facebook == null || profileRes[0].company_facebook == "") {
            point10 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].company_facebook != null || profileRes[0].company_facebook != "") {
            point10 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].number_of_employees == null || profileRes[0].number_of_employees == "") {
            point11 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].number_of_employees != null || profileRes[0].number_of_employees != "") {
            point11 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].company_logo == null || profileRes[0].company_logo == "") {
            point12 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].company_logo != null || profileRes[0].company_logo != "") {
            point12 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].founding_year == null || profileRes[0].founding_year == "") {
            point13 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].founding_year != null || profileRes[0].founding_year != "") {
            point13 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].is_profile_published == null || profileRes[0].is_profile_published == "") {
            point14 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].is_profile_published != null || profileRes[0].is_profile_published != "") {
            point14 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].legal_name == null || profileRes[0].legal_name == "") {
            point15 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].legal_name != null || profileRes[0].legal_name != "") {
            point15 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].billing_address == null || profileRes[0].billing_address == "") {
            point16 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].billing_address != null || profileRes[0].billing_address != "") {
            point16 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].zip_code == null || profileRes[0].zip_code == "") {
            point17 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].zip_code != null || profileRes[0].zip_code != "") {
            point17 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].vat_number == null || profileRes[0].vat_number == "") {
            point18 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].vat_number != null || profileRes[0].vat_number != "") {
            point18 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].sdi_codex == null || profileRes[0].sdi_codex == "") {
            point19 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].sdi_codex != null || profileRes[0].sdi_codex != "") {
            point19 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].benefits == null || profileRes[0].benefits == "") {
            point20 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].benefits != null || profileRes[0].benefits != "") {
            point20 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].category == null || profileRes[0].category == "") {
            point21 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].category != null || profileRes[0].category != "") {
            point21 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].branch == null || profileRes[0].branch == "") {
            point22 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].branch != null || profileRes[0].branch != "") {
            point22 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].coreActivities == null || profileRes[0].coreActivities == "") {
            point23 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].coreActivities != null || profileRes[0].coreActivities != "") {
            point23 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].districts == null || profileRes[0].districts == "") {
            point24 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].districts != null || profileRes[0].districts != "") {
            point24 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].legalFormCompany == null || profileRes[0].legalFormCompany == "") {
            point25 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].legalFormCompany != null || profileRes[0].legalFormCompany != "") {
            point25 = points += 0;

        }
        if (profileRes[0].commune == null || profileRes[0].commune == "") {
            point26 = points + 10;
        } else if (profileRes[0].commune != null || profileRes[0].commune != "") {
            point26 = points += 0;

        }
        else {

        
        }
        let pint = point1 + point2 + point3 + point4 + point5 + point6 + point7 + point8 + point9 + point10 +point11 + point12 + point13 + point14 + point15 + point16 + point17 + point18 + point19 + point20 + point21 + point22 + point23 + point24 + point25 + point26;

        let percentage = (pint * 100) / 260;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should all keys in the `profileRes[0]` have a corresponding points variable? If yes, then something like this might work. This solution will put all of your points into one object instead of a list of variables:

```js
const pointsMap = Object.entries(profileRes[0]).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = !!value ? 0 : 10
    return acc
}, {})

// returns an object that has key/value pairs accessible by the profileRes[0] keys
// for example, {username: 10, email: 0, phone: 10...}
```

Note, the above answer uses `!!value` to determine if the value is truthy. This means values like `null` and `""` will fail. `undefined` will also fail this check. If a key in `profileRes[0]` can be `undefined` and `undefined` should be considered a valid value, the line can change to be the following instead:

```
acc[key] = (value === null || value === "") ? 10 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the points variables

```
let points = 0;

for (let key in profileRes[0]) {
  if (profileRes[0][key] === null || profileRes[0][key] === '') {
    points += 10;
  } else {
    points += 0;
  }
}
let percentage = (points * 100) / 260;
```